# What's the difference between := and => in Ada?

Tags: pass-by-reference, ada, colon-equals

As far as I know, `:=` seems to do an assignation by copy. The operator `=>` seems to do a similar assignation, but is used when assigning a parameter to a member variable of an object.

so...

`receivesTheCopy := isBeingCopied`

`memberVariable => passedParameter`

I'm working on someone else's old code and I have a variable reaching a value that I never see explicitly assigned to it with `:=`. I was thinking that *maybe* when it is assigned to a `memberVariable` with `=>` it was passed by reference, and thus the `passedParameter` variable stayed tied to the `memberVariable` state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`:=` is an assignment.

`=>` has multiple purposes:

1. Parameter passing: Which formal parameter is passed which argument (if it isn't done by order).
2. Record and array aggregates: Which field gets which value.
3. Aspects: Separating aspect names from the expressions they are assigned.

In neither case it has anything to do with pass-by-reference or pass-by-value.

Comment: Hi @JacobSparreAndersen,
When you mention: "Parameter passing: Which formal parameter is passed which argument" 
wouldn't that be either pass-by-reference or pass-by-value?

Comment: When passing parameters, `=>` does nothing more than _associate_ a formal parameter name with an argument. The "pass by" semantics are governed by the parameter mode and the type of the parameter.

Comment: Ada parameter passing modes are IN, OUT, IN OUT. None of these modes specifies passing by reference or passing by value.